# DataJointError: Class ________ is not properly declared (schema decorator not applied?) when trying to diagram

Tags: datajoint

DataJoint version 0.13.4

Python 3.9, running in PyCharm 2022.1.1 Pro Edition

MacOS 12.3.1

I've been working with several of the datajoint-elements packages just trying to get an overall schema created so I can see what new schema's, if any, need to be created for hosting our lab's data. The blank for the class in the title is because I have seen this with several different classes while trying to get this setup, such as `Class Session` or `Class SessionNote`. In the code below, `Class SessionNote` is what the actual error was for, but I figured a more general question may help others in the future!

What I especially find interesting is that this error occurs when just calling the draw function for `lab` which by itself does not have any reference to `SessionNote`. I also tried not activating the other schema by commenting them out, and then would instead get the same error, but for `Class Subject` not being properly declared. I have double checked and all the classes that are claiming to not be properly declared are active within the namespace of the environment. I have also gotten this error when trying to insert data into a table, though that seems fixed after I updated one of the elements packages straight from github instead of PyPi. Let me know if there is any additional information I can provide to help! It's my first submission to Stack Overflow

```
import datetime

import datajoint as dj
import wehrdj
from element_session import session
from element_animal import subject, genotyping
from element_lab import lab


from element_animal.subject import Subject
from element_animal.genotyping import Sequence, BreedingPair, Cage,\
                                      SubjectCaging, GenotypeTest
from element_lab.lab import Source, Lab, Protocol, User, Project, ProjectUser, \
                            ProjectKeywords, ProjectPublication, ProjectSourceCode
from element_session.session_with_datetime import Session, SessionDirectory, \
                            SessionExperimenter, SessionNote, \
                            ProjectSession
from element_animal.export.nwb import subject_to_nwb
from element_lab.export.nwb import element_lab_to_nwb_dict

wehrdj.connect()  # Wrapper for dj.connect(), can be replaced with the normal DJ function if needed

db_prefix = dj.config['custom'].get('database.prefix', '')

__all__ = ['genotyping', 'session', 'Subject', 'Source', 'Lab', 'Protocol', 'User',
           'Project', 'ProjectKeywords', 'ProjectPublication', 'ProjectSourceCode',
           'ProjectUser', 'Session', 'SessionDirectory', 'SessionExperimenter',
           'SessionNote', 'ProjectSession', 'Sequence', 'BreedingPair', 'Cage',
           'SubjectCaging', 'GenotypeTest']

Experimenter = lab.User

# Testing activations
lab.activate(db_prefix + "lab")
subject.activate(db_prefix + "subject", linking_module=__name__)
session.activate(db_prefix + "session", linking_module=__name__)
genotyping.activate(db_prefix + "genotyping", db_prefix + "subject", linking_module=__name__)

# Testing drawing schema
dj.Diagram(lab).draw()
```

Comment: I think the public version of element-session offers 2 options depending on how you want to identify a session. You might change the import to `from element_session import session_with_id as session`

Comment: Changing both element-session calls to specify `from element_session import session_with_id as session` and `from element_session.session_with_id import Session, SessionDirectory, SessionExperimenter, SessionNote, ProjectSession` still seems to result in the same initial error. I did notice that when calling session as I did, it does default to calling the `session_with_datetime` option, but I agree your suggestion is better for readability!

Comment: Hmm, not sure. Can it be stripped down to an MVP? I would save the above as `pipeline.py` with just the lab items. And then `from project.pipeline import lab` - if you run `dj.conn()`, is there a lab schema on the server? // Minor additional note: `genotyping.activate` can bump up 2 lines and replace `subject.activate` - Genotyping is one of the schemas that activates another schema in the same element.

Comment: So separating it into just the lab items did cause the lab schema to diagram properly! I went back to the original code I submitted above and that actually works too now with no modifications. Is there any inkling as to why running the separate lab instance first has solved this problem?

Comment: Sorry, no, not sure why. It does seem specific to the Element activation process. Production schemas elsewhere [e.g.](https://github.com/BrainCOGS/U19-pipeline_python/blob/master/u19_pipeline/behavior.py) don't need the same activation because they know the prefix+schema name at time of declaration. I might be able to tell you more with the full error stack. Could be something with the connection?